# Принцип минимальной информированности, когда можно нарушать?

Tags: ооп, архитектура, solid

Вот пример такой композиции в коде, как я понимаю нарушает принцип минимальной информированности (Principle of Least Knowledge) ([см. Закон Деметры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)):

```
class A:

    def method1(self):
        pass

    def method2(self):
        pass

    def method3(self):
        pass


class B:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = A

    def method1(self):
        pass


b = B()
b.a.method1()
```

Однако, я заметил, что часто используют такой подход для расширения интерфейса класса.

Пример из джавы и C#:

```
System.out.println()
```

Пример из Джанго:

```
MyModel.objects.create()
```

Вот и интересно, когда расширять класс таким образом можно считать правильным?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ограничения накладываются согласно здравому смыслу и предметной области.

Я напишу о человеке. Человек, в большинстве случаев, может двигать конечностями, думать головой и делать ещё какие то действия, которые довольно поверхностны.
Если вы пишете игру и человеки там - не предмет каких то модификаций, то доступны у них должны быть те же операции, что и в реальной жизни.
*Стоит иметь в виду, что для мед. оборудования или игр с модификацией людей - доступ может быть намного шире.*

Простой пример - `человек.рука.двигать()`.

Что бы ни случилось в реализации, такой код останется валидным и не должен превращаться в `человек.ДвигатьРукой()` или `человек.Двигать(рука)`.

---

При этом, люди не умеют контролировать конкретные мышцы в руке, к примеру, а значит, объект должен скрывать собой внутренности реализации.

Т.е. `рука.Двигать()` но не `рука.мышцы[x].двинуть(y, z)`.

---

Ещё проще - когда свойство обязательно и неизменно, обосновано предметной областью - можно ссылаться на него, иначе его должен скрывать основной класс.

Comment: Уточните, чем `рука.мышцы` принципиально отличается от `человек.рука`. Редко, но ведь бывает у `человека` нету `рук`. То есть где именно должна проходить граница между "такое свойство всегда есть и мы к нему можем обращаться" и "такое свойство есть не всегда и к нему обращаться нельзя"

Comment: @Kromster это сложный вопрос уровня предметной области. Если вы занимаетесь медицинским оборудованием - вам может потребоваться доступ к мышцам руки, не спорю. Во всех остальных случаях доступ к ним должен быть закрыт, для имитации реального мира. ПС: а если нет рук, то это типичный `NRE`, пусть сыплется.

Comment: поэтому и хорошо бы уточнить, согласно каким критериям свойства допустимо вызывать паровозиком или нет.

Comment: Направление мысли понял. Спасибо за пояснения.

Comment: @МистерФикс не торопитесь с принятием ответа, возможно кто-то напишет понятнее. В любом случае, рад помочь.

Answer (score 8):

Для начала нужно разобраться в чем проблема, когда один объект выставляет свои внутренности наружу, после чего станет понятным, когда это проблемой не является.

Инкапсуляция и сокрытие информации направлены на упрощение разработки. [Хороший дизайн](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2013/01/blog-post_29.html) позволяет сосредоточиться на минимальном числе концепций в один момент времени и ограничивает число изменений минимальным числом модулей в случае изменения требований.

Когда объект выставляет свои внутренности наружу, то это может привести к более хрупкому решению. По своей природе, открытый интерфейс класса должен быть более стабильным, а детали реализации – скрытыми от его клиентов. В этом случае, реализация может быть заменена, не нарушая работу клиентов.

Когда в открытый интерфейс просачиваются детали реализации, в виде открытых полей или даже свойств, то это ограничивает возможности автора класса на изменения.
Код вида `A.B.C.D.E.Foo()` обладает низкой стабильностью, поскольку внесение изменений в один из 5 классов наверняка его сломает.

С другой стороны, не любое открытое свойство раскрывает детали реализации. Иногда, подобные свойства являются частью самой сути решаемой проблемы. Например, у квадрата есть координаты и обращение вида: `square.Position.X` вполне может быть оправданным.

Иногда, приходится нарушать данное правило по другой причине, например, при разработке библиотек.

Любая сложная система является иерархической, и нам просто необходимо группировать связанные концепции. Тот же `System.out` из мира Java является подобным примером. Мы хотим объединить все системные операции за некоторым фасадом, который будет удобной точкой входа для исследования. В этом плане мы не собираемся перемещать `out` в другой класс, и точно не будем дублировать операции из `PrintStream` в классе `System`.

Итак, в качестве заключения: **закон Деметры не нарушается, если отношение целое-часть является частью предметной области. Закон Деметры не нарушается в случае фасадных классов, единственная задача которых предоставить доступ к некоторым объеткам.**

Но закон Деметры нарушается, если выставленное свойство является деталью реализации, которая может измениться в будущем.

Comment: Фасадный класс вообще-то скрывает интерфейсы классов которые он вмещает, за своим интерфейсом, а не предоставляет к ним доступ.

Comment: Согласен, в этом случае это не вполне себе фасад, но и не класс со своим собственным поведением.