# Композиция объектов. Есть ли смысл соблюдать "закон деметры", в больших классах

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, архитектура, проектирование, solid

**Стараюсь наработать навыки проектирования по правилам SOLID.**

Есть большой логически связанный класс, представляющий объект реального мира.
Предположим в классе есть около сорока методов, которые представляют поведение этого объекта.

Предположительно методов может быть и сотня. Если они связаны логически, то это разрешается, как я понял.

Но ведь использовать их неудобно. Хочется категорий, чтобы с классом было удобнее работать.

Написал похожий класс тремя разными способами. Старался, согласно рекомендациям, использовать композицию вместо наследования.

**Car** - *наиболее прост, но если методов будет сорок или сто, то неудобно, и может быть тяжело в нём разобраться спустя время.*

**Car2** - *представляет из себя композицию, но нарушает "закон Деметры", из правил SOLID, так как клиент знает не только о Car2, но и о его друзьях.*

**Car3** - *ничего не нарушает, каждая категория инкапсулирована, но по количеству методов одинаков с первой версией, что не очень удобно.*

Мне вот кажется наиболее удобной вторая версия. Третья же по количеству методов не отличается от первой, но вроде как самая правильная.

Если кто разбирается, укажите на ошибки. Правильный ли подход я выбрал? Какой из способов наиболее подходящий?

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self):
        self._speed = 0
        self._name = "Car"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def speed(self):
        return self._speed

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def turn_left(self): pass

    def turn_right(self): pass

    def accelerate(self): pass

    def brake(self): pass

    def windscreen_wiper_on(self): pass

    def windscreen_wiper_of(self): pass


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Car2():

    def __init__(self):
        self._speed = 0
        self._name = "Car"
        self._stering_wheel = SteringWheel(self)
        self._gas_pedal = GasPedal(self)
        self._windscreen_wiper = WindscreenWiper(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def speed(self):
        return self._speed

    @speed.setter
    def speed(self, value):
        self._speed = value
        print("Новая скорость машины:", self._speed)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @property
    def stering_wheel(self):
        return self._stering_wheel

    @property
    def gas_pedal(self):
        return self._gas_pedal

    @property
    def windscreen_wiper(self):
        return self._windscreen_wiper


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Car3:
    def __init__(self):
        self._speed = 0
        self._name = "Car"
        self._stering_wheel = SteringWheel(self)
        self._gas_pedal = GasPedal(self)
        self._windscreen_wiper = WindscreenWiper(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def speed(self):
        return self._speed

    @speed.setter
    def speed(self, value):
        self._speed = value
        print("Новая скорость машины:", self._speed)


    def turn_left(self):
        self._stering_wheel.turn_left()

    def turn_right(self):
        self._stering_wheel.turn_right()

    def accelerate(self):
        car.gas_pedal.press()

    def brake(self):
        car.gas_pedal.depress()

    def windscreen_wiper_on(self):
        car.windscreen_wiper.on()

    def windscreen_wiper_of(self):
        car.windscreen_wiper.off()



# ---------------------------- Компоненты машины ------------------------------
class SteringWheel:

    def __init__(self, car: Car):
        self._car = car

    def rotate_left(self):
        print(self._car.name, "повернула влево")

    def rotate_right(self):
        print(self._car.name, "повернула вправо")


class GasPedal:

    def __init__(self, car: Car):
        self._car = car

    def press(self):
        self._car.speed += 1

    def depress(self):
        self._car.speed -= 1


class WindscreenWiper:

    def __init__(self, car: Car):
        self._car = car

    def on(self):
        print("Дворники", self._car.name, "очищают окно.")

    def off(self):
        print("Дворники", self._car.name, "выключились.")


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    car = Car2()
    car.gas_pedal.press()
    car.gas_pedal.press()
    car.gas_pedal.depress()
    car.windscreen_wiper.on()
    car.windscreen_wiper.off()
    car.stering_wheel.rotate_left()


main()
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560468/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй вариант проще и понятнее. Надо только чуть иначе его рассматривать.

Закон Деметры говорит о том, что "водитель" не должен знать о том *как* реализовано управление автомобилем - рулем, штурвалом или веревочками. Но если у автомобиля всегда есть сущность для управления (*управлятель*), то его вполне можно вынести в отдельный класс и использовать как `car.steering.something`.

То же относится и к `gas_pedal` - нельзя ее "показывать" наружу в таком виде. Вдруг вместо нее будет реостат или рычаги. А вот если ее "выставить" как контроль скорости (`accelerator`), то все будет в порядке.

Если вы можете у класса выделить поведение, реализуемое всеми его потомками, и это поведение неотрывно от класса (т.е. каждая машину будет иметь управлятель и контролер_скорости), то его вполне можно вынести в отдельный класс (и в этом классе подставлять разные реализации).

По сути, со 2 способом, вы получаете:

А. Древовидную группировку методов:

```
car.steering_left
   .steering_right
   .steering_center
   .gaspedal_more
   .gaspedal_less

car.steering.left
            .right
            .center
   .gaspedal.more
            .less
```

Б. Возможность подмены реализации компонентов.

P.S. В догонку, для размышления - Best Practices могут быть хороши в 80-99,9% случаев, но всегда найдется %, когда goto или 12 входных параметров, или метод из 120 строк будут оправданными, проще или лучше, чем следование *общим хорошим* правилам.

Comment: Когда рисуешь диаграмму, то сразу визуализируется куча зависимостей. То есть связанность всё-таки увеличивается.

Comment: В вики написано: **Аналогия из жизни: Если Вы хотите, чтобы собака побежала, глупо командовать её лапами, лучше отдать команду собаке, а она уже разберётся со своими лапами сама.** То есть получается, что я должен отдавать команду машине, а не рулю, походу. Я этот момент не догоняю до сих пор.

Comment: @МистерФикс обратите внимание, на то, что я разделил *руль* и *управлятель*. Второе - позволяет скрывать детали реализации. Вы отдаете управлятелю общие высокоуровневые команды (повернуть левее на 10 градусов), тогда как с рулем вам нужно было бы знать о том что он руль (а не парус, например), о том какое у него передаточное число к колесам и т.п.

Comment: @МистерФикс В случае с собакой, идет некоторая подмена понятий. Мы так привыкли, что все собаки четырехлапы, и упрощение (собака может только бегать и лаять), что забываем о том, что собаки могут так же иметь сотню более специфичных методов, которые надо как-то разделять и группировать, причем по неочевидным природным понятиям, а по используемой предметной области. Например, мы могли бы детализировать собаку для перемещения, издавания звуков и играния.

Comment: да вы правильно говорите. На счёт специфичных методов тоже. Вот тут и возникает проблема. С одной сторону группировать удобно, а с другой, это увеличивает связанность между классами или модулями. Интерфейс же, через который вы предлагаете связать, классы, нужен не всегда, а только если предполагается расширение типов управления.

Comment: @МистерФикс Как и со всеми решениями - надо стараться соблюсти баланс между плюсами и минусами. Обычно, если можно выделить 10+ методов (и это менее 40% методов класса) в новый подкласс, если вы можете их логически сгруппировать и обосновать - оно того стоит. Интерфейс - вовсе не обязателен, но я его упомянул, как дополнительный критерий оценки и возможность к расширению.

Comment: спасибо. Ваш ответ очень хороший.